# Sampling from static data set to create dataframe, ignore index in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I am trying to create some random samples (of a given size) from a static dataframe. The goal is to create multiple columns for each sample (and each sample drawn is the same size). I'm expecting to see multiple columns of the same length (i.e. sample size) in the fully sampled dataframe, but maybe append isn't the right way to go. Here is the code:

```
# create sample dataframe
    target_df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000))
    target_df.columns=['pl']

# create the sampler:

    sample_num = 5
    sample_len = 10
    df_max_row = len(target_df) - sample_len 
      

 for i in range(sample_num):
        rndm_start = np.random.choice(df_max_row, 1)[0]
        rndm_end = rndm_start + sample_len
        slicer = target_df.iloc[rndm_start:rndm_end]['pl']
        
sampled_df = sampled_df.append(slicer, ignore_index=True)
sampled_df = sampled_df.T
```

The output of this is shown in the pic below - The red line shows the index I want remove.

[image: actual output]

The desired output is shown below that. How do I make this happen?

[image: desired output]

Thanks!

Comment: why not `sampled_df[str(i)] = slicer.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create new column using

```
sampled_df[i] = slicer.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Eventually I would use `str(i)` for column name because later it is simpler to select column using string than number

```
import pandas as pd
import random

target_df = pd.DataFrame({'pl': range(1000)})

# create the sampler:

sample_num = 5
sample_len = 10
df_max_row = len(target_df) - sample_len 

sampled_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1, sample_num+1):
    start = random.randint(0, df_max_row)
    end   = start + sample_len
    slicer = target_df[start:end]['pl']
    sampled_df[str(i)] = slicer.reset_index(drop=True)

sampled_df.index += 1 
print(sampled_df)
```

Result:

```
      1    2    3    4    5
1   735  396  646  534  769
2   736  397  647  535  770
3   737  398  648  536  771
4   738  399  649  537  772
5   739  400  650  538  773
6   740  401  651  539  774
7   741  402  652  540  775
8   742  403  653  541  776
9   743  404  654  542  777
10  744  405  655  543  778
```

But to create really random values then I would  first shuffle values

```
np.random.shuffle(target_df['pl'])
```

and then I don't have to use `random` to select `start`

`shuffle` changes original column so it can't assign to new variable.

It doesn't repeat values in samples.

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import random

target_df = pd.DataFrame({'pl': range(1000)})

# create the sampler:

sample_num = 5
sample_len = 10

sampled_df = pd.DataFrame()

#np.random.shuffle(target_df['pl'])
random.shuffle(target_df['pl'])

for i in range(1, sample_num+1):
    start = i * sample_len
    end   = start + sample_len
    slicer = target_df[start:end]['pl']
    sampled_df[str(i)] = slicer.reset_index(drop=True)

sampled_df.index += 1 
print(sampled_df)
```

Result:

```
      1    2    3    4    5
1   638  331  171  989  170
2    22  643   47  136  764
3   969  455  211  763  194
4   859  384  174  552  566
5   221  829   62  926  414
6     4  895  951  967  381
7   758  688  594  876  873
8   757  691  825  693  707
9   235  353   34  699  121
10  447   81   36  682  251
```

---

If values can repeat then you could use

```
sampled_df[str(i)] = target_df['pl'].sample(n=sample_len, ignore_index=True)
```

```
import pandas as pd

target_df = pd.DataFrame({'pl': range(1000)})

# create the sampler:

sample_num = 5
sample_len = 10

sampled_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1, sample_num+1):
    sampled_df[str(i)] = target_df['pl'].sample(n=sample_len, ignore_index=True)

sampled_df.index += 1 
print(sampled_df)
```

---

**EDIT**

You may also get shuffled values as `numpy array` and use `reshape` - and later convert back to `DataFrame` with many columns. And later you can get some columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

target_df = pd.DataFrame({'pl': range(1000)})

# create the sampler:

sample_num = 5
sample_len = 10

random.shuffle(target_df['pl'])

sampled_df = pd.DataFrame(target_df['pl'].values.reshape([sample_len,-1]))

sampled_df = sampled_df.iloc[:, 0:sample_num]

sampled_df.index += 1
print(sampled_df)
```

Comment: genius!!! thanks! @furas

Comment: I added example with `numpy array` and `reshape`